# Counts of words in string by group using pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I want to get the top 20 frequent words, along with counts, by standard_supplier_name

here is what my dataframe looks like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOrjz.png

I want my output to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/07iaA.png

can someone help me out with this?

Comment: please post your data as text so we can test a solution against your data.

Comment: [value counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'standard_supplier_name':['ibl america', 'b.v. shie van'], 
                  'index':['aa, human, tag, bachulovius,slam, family, member, aa , human,tag',
                         'aanbrengen, looproute, bij']})

df = df.set_index('index')

#input df

df.reset_index()\
  .set_index('standard_supplier_name')['index'].str.split(',')\
  .explode().str.strip().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
human          2
tag            2
aa             2
looproute      1
bij            1
aanbrengen     1
member         1
family         1
bachulovius    1
slam           1
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at what you are trying to achieve.

In the future, try to provide datasets, and a minimal reproducible example.

```
desc = ["aa, bc, cd, cd, aa, bb", "xy, jk, yb"]
comp = ["abc", "xyz"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"comp": comp, "desc":desc})
#split words into tokens
df["desc"] = df.desc.str.split(", ")
#stack words per group
stacked = pd.DataFrame(df.desc.tolist(), index=df.comp).stack().reset_index()
stacked.columns = ["comp", "drop", "token"] 

#group by comp and token and count occurances
stacked.groupby(["comp","token"]).size().reset_index()
```